# delphi excel Hyperlink in a cell

Tags: delphi, excel

How can I extract a hyperlink from some cell in excel table using Delphi?

Comment: What do you get when you try to extract the contents of the cell?

Comment: I get text of the hyperlink, but not it's address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the [`Hyperlinks.Address`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb148518%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property

check this code

```
var
  excel : Variant;
begin
 Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');//Create an excel instance
 try
 Excel.Workbooks.Open('yourexcelfile.xls'); //open the excel workbook
 if Excel.Range['B4', 'B4'].Hyperlinks.Count > 0 then //check if exist hyperlinks in the range
  ShowMessage(Excel.Range['B4', 'B4'].Hyperlinks[1].Address); //show the hyperlink
 finally
 if not VarIsEmpty(Excel) then
  Excel.Quit; //Close the excel instance
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 50 bucks in your budget for a slick library of Delphi code to read and write Excel files without using OLE or requiring Excel to be present, you could try [NativeExcel](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/).  It's fast, easy to use, comes with a to-the-point help file, and gives you great control over the workbooks you create.  Here's the code to read the value from A1:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  Var Book: IXLSWorkbook;
  ws: IXLSWorksheet;
  sHyperlink: String;
begin
  Book := TXLSWorkbook.Create;
  Book.Open('C:\Data\Book1.xls');
  ws := Book.Sheets[1];
  ShowMessage(ws.Range['A1','A1'].HyperLinks[1].Address);
end;
```